# Sending a string using TcpClient in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, tcp

My tcp client has made a connection to the server script! Now that it has connected, how can it send a simple string? I do not know what any of the overloads for the .Client.Send method even mean, or how to use them. I already have a system set up on the server side to parse the string when it is received on the server side, but I have no idea how to send a simple string to it.

Thanks for the help!

This is in vb.net by the way.

Comment: [This article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020323.asp) should point you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading but your code for sending information into one subroutine then place your code for receiving information into a completely different subrouting then place the two different subroutines onto two different threads like so

```
Imports System.Threading.Thread

Dim SendThread as threading.thread
Dim ReceiveThread as threading.thread

SendThread = new threading.thread(addressof "Name of Subroutine")
sendthread.start()
```

etc do the same thing with receiving network packets